# Python Dataframe Using Questions

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

I have 2 dataframe, which are created by running sql in python:

TableA:

| C | Email | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c | E | E1 |
| c | E | E2 |
| c | E | E3 |
| c | F | F1 |
| c | F | F2 |

TableB:

| D | Code | Info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d | E1 | ... |
| g | E3 | ... |
| d | F1 | ... |
| g | E2 | ... |
| d | F1 | ... |
| g | E2 | ... |
| d | F1 | ... |
| g | E1 | ... |
| d | F1 | ... |

I would like to send all the information belongs to `E` from `TableB` to `E`.
And I need to send all the information belongs to `F` from `TableB` to `F` too.

For example,

1. Sending the `tableB` below to `E`

| foo | bar |
| --- | --- |
| baz | bim |

Can I know there is someone knowing how to do it?

Comment: You need to include a sample data and the output you want.

Comment: This sounds like a [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), but the kind of join that you want is not clear to me. If you provide some sample data and output, that would clarify things.

Comment: Not very clear how to go from input to output.

Comment: maybe you should run SQL query to get it directly from database as one table.

Comment: Pandas doc: [Merge, join, concatenate and compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can `merge` dataframes

```
t1 = '''C   Email   Code
c   E   E1
c   E   E2
c   E   E3
c   F   F1
c   F   F2'''

t2 = '''D   Code    Info
d   E1  ...
g   E3  ...
d   F1  ...
g   E2  ...
d   F1  ...
g   E2  ...
d   F1  ...
g   E1  ...
d   F1  ...'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t1), sep='\s+')
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t2), sep='\s+')

print(df1)
print(df2)

result = pd.merge(df1,  df2)#, on=['Code'])

print(result)
```

Result:

```
   C Email Code
0  c     E   E1
1  c     E   E2
2  c     E   E3
3  c     F   F1
4  c     F   F2

   D Code Info
0  d   E1  ...
1  g   E3  ...
2  d   F1  ...
3  g   E2  ...
4  d   F1  ...
5  g   E2  ...
6  d   F1  ...
7  g   E1  ...
8  d   F1  ...

   C Email Code  D Info
0  c     E   E1  d  ...
1  c     E   E1  g  ...
2  c     E   E2  g  ...
3  c     E   E2  g  ...
4  c     E   E3  g  ...
5  c     F   F1  d  ...
6  c     F   F1  d  ...
7  c     F   F1  d  ...
8  c     F   F1  d  ...
```

More in Pandas doc: [Merge, join, concatenate and compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to send to every user all in one mail then you can group by `Email`

```
groups = result.groupby('Email')

for value, group in groups:
    print('Email:', value)
    print(group)
```

Result:

```
Email: E
   C Email Code  D Info
0  c     E   E1  d  ...
1  c     E   E1  g  ...
2  c     E   E2  g  ...
3  c     E   E2  g  ...
4  c     E   E3  g  ...

Email: F
   C Email Code  D Info
5  c     F   F1  d  ...
6  c     F   F1  d  ...
7  c     F   F1  d  ...
8  c     F   F1  d  ...
```